# How do I detect transitions away from my current UIView?

Tags: ios5, uiview

I'm looking to execute some code on any transitions away from my current UIView. The view itself is probably going to stick around and not be garbage collected, so viewDidUnload is probably not the appropriate event.

Is there another event, or method, for detecting when a given view is no longer being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;`
OR
`-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;`
depends on business logic you want to implement